# Diferencia entre for y FOR

Tags: c++

buenas noches. Mi pregunta surge de que estaba viendo un Youtuber participando en una competencia de programación y observando, noté en ocasiones usaba la estructura for pero en otros casos lo escribia como FOR. ¿Existe alguna diferencia entre estos casos?. Soy estudiante de ingenieria en sistemas de segundo semestre y me surgen varias inquietudes.

Comment: Creo que no había, o si la había, no se veía en el vídeo.

Comment: `FOR` no existe en [tag:c++].

Answer (score 5):

Esto es algo común en las competiciones de programación. FOR no es algo que exista en C++. Lo que algunos programadores hacen es definirlo al inicio del programa como un macro para no tener que escribir toda la estructura de control.

La definición y su uso se verían así:

```
#define FOR(i,n) for (i = 0; i < n; i++)

int main()
{
  int j, n = 10;
  FOR(j, n)
  {
    std::cout << "mensaje #" << j << "\n";
  }
}
```

He de recalcar que esto se hace solo por conveniencia y para ahorrar tiempo escribiendo el código durante la competición. En un proyecto real, este tipo de definiciones son malas prácticas que la gente suele adquirir al meterse a este tipo de competiciones antes de conocer suficientemente bien el lenguaje.

Answer (score -1):

No hay diferencia, pero dependiendo del lenguaje de programación y del motor, si es sensible o no a mayúsculas y minúsculas, tendrá el mismo resultado.

Comment: Ah, ok. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De acuerdo a las etiquetas de la pregunta, el lenguaje de programación es _c++_, en donde SI que hay diferencia.